# how to create an object from Field.getType() reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I create an reflection function to create a new object and set data inside.

This is my code but, i dont know how to fill object declaration class type:

`<Class-Type> newObj = f.getType().getConstructor(new Class[]{}).newInstance();`

f is a java.lang.reflect.Field that i get from class.getDeclaredFields()

i already try using Object type

`Object newObj = f.getType().getConstructor(new Class[]{}).newInstance();`

but after i invoke data

`Method setterNewObj =newObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + Character.toUpperCase(m.getName().charAt(0))+ m.getName().substring(1), m.getType());
 setterNewObj.invoke(newObj, this.typeConvert(mapOfValue.get(nameOfColumn), m.getType()));`

and i print.out the result data is not set (null);

Thanks

Comment: It is hard to tell without complete piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

From what we can see, your code is not wrong.
Perhaps you need to provide a more complete code sample or some extra information of what you do, so we can check.

I have created a small piece of code (complete and runnable) to show you that it works:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Buddy {  
    String name;  
    Buddy buddy;

    public Buddy() {}

    public Buddy(String n) {  
        this();
        name = n;  
    }  

    public void setBuddy(Buddy b) {
        if (this.buddy != null)
            this.buddy.buddy = null;
        this.buddy = b;
        b.buddy = this;
    }  

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String getInfo() {
        return name;
    }

    public void display() {
        if (buddy != null)
            System.out.println(this.getInfo() +" & "+ buddy.getInfo());
        else
            System.out.println(this.getInfo());
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Buddy s1 = new Buddy("Rick");  
        s1.display();

        System.out.println("\nNeeds his buddy 'Morty' :");
        Buddy s2 = new Buddy("Morty");
        s1.setBuddy(s2);
        s1.display();
        s2.display();

        System.out.println("\nChange to new buddy 'Roller':");
        try {
            // Get the buddy field
            Field f = s1.getClass().getDeclaredField("buddy");

            // Create a new Buddy instance
            Object newObj = f.getType().getConstructor(new Class[]{}).newInstance();

            // Get the name field
            Field m = newObj.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");

            // Get the setter for the name field
            Method setterNewObj = newObj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + Character.toUpperCase(m.getName().charAt(0))+ m.getName().substring(1), m.getType());

            // Invoke the setter for the name field with a value
            setterNewObj.invoke(newObj, "Roller");

            // Get the setter for the buddy field
            Method setterS1 = s1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("set" + Character.toUpperCase(f.getName().charAt(0))+ f.getName().substring(1), f.getType());

            // Invoke the setter for the buddy field with the new Buddy instance
            setterS1.invoke(s1, newObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        s1.display();
        s2.display();
    }
}
```

Which you can see prints the newly created buddy and the old buddy still exists:

> Rick
>
> Needs his buddy 'Morty' :
>   Rick & Morty
>   Morty & Rick
>
> Change to new buddy 'Roller':
>   Rick & Roller
>   Morty